# Passing List of object from view to controller error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all following is  my ondemand feed model code

```
public class OndemandFeedModel
{
    public CountryModel Country { get; set; }
    public FieldSelectModel Fields { get; set; }
    public FilterSelectModel Filters { get; set; }
}


 public class FieldSelectModel
    {
    public List<FieldGroup> FieldGroup { get; set; }
   }


 public class FieldGroup
 {
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<FieldModel> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class FieldModel
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public int FieldId { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string UserDefinedFieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldGroup { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

}
```

and when i hit the Httppost it will give the following error

[image]
[image]

I don know what went wrong . Can anyone help me

Comment: Where did you expect the `Fields` property to be populated?

Comment: The default model binder will bind via index.. if you render them in the view with an index.. e.g: a `for..loop`.

Comment: @JonSkeet actually my view is like  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746591/how-to-get-the-old-and-user-defined-name-for-the-checked-values-in-mvc-asp-net this and once i click the submit button i have to get the selected fields and have to form a JSON to call REST

Comment: Could you please post your view?

Comment: @ssilas777 refer this link you can see my view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746591/how-to-get-the-old-and-user-defined-name-for-the-checked-values-in-mvc-asp-net

Comment: Could you please post your Action code that loads the view?

Comment: @AbbasAmiri for which type either for HttpGet or for HttpPost .

Comment: @Backtrack for HttpGet

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to see `Request.Form.AllKeys` to see what got posted.

Your HTML input fields should map hierarchical naming of your Model Object Graph, or the model binder will not bind it to the model.

Also, for start, while posting collections you can post a hidden with starting index of the collection (if it is anything but 0).

Answer (score 0):

As per above code `[HttpPost]` should not integrate with Index method
because Index method should always `[httpGet]` otherwise it will give 404 error. On page load it always give null values as already mentioned.
You can take help from below example:

```
interface IProductRepository
{
IEnumerable<Product> GetAll();
}

public class Product
{
    [Display(Name = "Product ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class ProductRepository 
{
    private List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

    public ProductRepository()
    {
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 1, Name = "xyz", Category = "Cat A", Price = 1 });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 2, Name = "xyz", Category = "Cat B", Price = 100 });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 3, Name = "xyz", Category = "Cat C", Price = 1000 });
        products.Add(new Product { ID = 4, Name = "xyz", Category = "Cat D", Price = 10000 });
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return products;
    }        

}

    public ActionResult Index(Product model)
    {   
        repository.GetAll();
        //put foreach() here...
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: @Nithin Index page cant have HTTPPOST ??

Comment: HttpPost attribute should not be implemented with Index method. Index method should always be HttpGet

`[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(Product model)
    {   
        repository.GetAll();
        //put foreach() here...
        return View();
    }`